# Windows 11 - How Can I Change the Taskbar Icon or Actual Icon of Windows Terminal

Tags: taskbar, icons, windows-11, desktop-customization, microsoft-store

Microsoft makes it extremely difficult to make any changes to "modern" Windows apps.

For most non-MS Store applications, you can simply place a shortcut with a modified icon in the Start Menu folder and this will change the displayed Taskbar icon for the program.

If I try to do this with a Microsoft Store app, **the taskbar icon turns into a black square!**

On the other hand, trying to directly modify the executable with Resource Hacker also did not seem to work (and is probably a bad option anyways if you want the app to be updated).

Is there any way I can modify either the taskbar icon or actual icon for Windows Terminal? (Since as far as I know, it is impossible to install it as a normal standalone application due to MS's "heavy encouragement" of MS Store)

I am on Windows 11 version 21H2.

I have already tried the solution here, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70413031/change-the-taskbar-icon-for-windows-store-apps but it is either outdated or does not work for Windows Terminal. **I should mention that Windows bugged  and my memory usage skyrocketed when I tired placing the shortcut in my start menu folder and running it**; the only way I could fix this was by deleting the shortcut from the folder. If someone can get this solution working, please post a detailed answer explaining how.

I am open to 3rd party software suggestions if there is no native way to change a Microsoft Store app's taskbar icon like John suggested.

Comment: Is there any simple way I can modify either the taskbar icon or actual icon for Windows Terminal?    ....No native way at all.